# Integrate Google App to my ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, google-apps

I need to use google accounts in my ASP.NET application. Did somebody do it? I have many questions about it

Comment: I did this website a while ago : http://www.campingrama.com/

But you'll have to give more details if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow does it. Use the OAuth/OpenID libraries for .NET - [DotNotOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).